# How to make pd.Dataframe column assignment faster?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, assign

So I am trying to add columns to an existing dataframe with mostly logical comparisons:

```
def qualitycheck(data, qparams, qid):
    data = data.assign(parameter_set = qid)
    data = data.assign(volume_below_max = (data["volume"] < int(qparams["max_volume"])))
    data = data.assign(volume_trucks_below_max = (data["volume_trucks"]  < int(qparams["max_volume_trucks"])))
    data = data.assign(volume_cars_below_max = (data["volume_cars"] < int(qparams["max_volume_cars"])))
    data = data.assign(volume_diffcheck_ok = diffcheck(data["volume"]))
    data = data.assign(occupancy_below_max = data["occupancy"]  < int(qparams["max_occupancy"]))
    data = data.assign(occupancy_diffcheck_ok = diffcheck(data["occupancy"]))
    data = data.assign(speed_below_max = data["speed"] < int(qparams["max_speed"]))
    data = data.assign(speed_trucks_below_max= data["speed_trucks"]  < int(qparams["max_speed_trucks"]))
    data = data.assign(speed_cars_below_max = data["speed_cars"] < int(qparams["max_speed_cars"]))
    data = data.assign(speed_diffcheck_ok = diffcheck(data["speed"]))
    data = data.assign(volume_speed_plausible = q_v_plaus(data["volume"], data["speed"]))
    data = data.assign(net_time_gap_below_max = data["net_time_gap"] < 60)
    data = data.assign(speed_occupancy_plausible = v_occ_plaus(data["speed"], data["occupancy"], qparams))   
return data
```

The three functions used in those .assigns are also just some logical comparisons of the two columns provided. 'qparams' is a DataFrame with one row with some constants. Each time this qualitycheck()-Function is called a data frame with 5 rows is passed in, which will then be expanded by these 14 columns and returned. With %timeit I get a time of 11.9ms for this function. The problem is, I have to call it around 25 Million times, which would lead to like 83h.

So is there any way to improve the performance of this function?

edit: here are the three functions:

```
def diffcheck(column):
    if column.sum() == 0:
        return True
    val0 = column.iloc[0]
    check = val0 == column
    if check.sum() < len(check):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def q_v_plaus(qs,vs):
    plaus = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        q = qs.iloc[i]
        v = vs.iloc[i]
        if q == 0 and v > 0:
            plaus.append(False)
        elif q > 0 and v == 0:
            plaus.append(False)
        else:
            plaus.append(True)
    return plaus
```

Comment: In my opinion main problem should be  in your function `diffcheck`, `q_v_plaus`, `v_occ_plaus`, can you add this functions to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is you call this function for 5 rows chunks, better performance should be for 1k, 10k rows chunks.

Function [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) is a bit slowier, but main problem should be in your custom functions `diffcheck`, `q_v_plaus`, `v_occ_plaus` - I guess not vectorized (if possible or not it is not possible say without see it).

A bit faster is remove `assign` and compare by `.values` for replace `Series` to `1d numpy array`:

```
def qualitycheck(data, qparams, qid):
    data['parameter_set'] = qid
    data['volume_below_max'] = data["volume"].values < int(qparams["max_volume"])
    ...
    ...
```

I try optimalized your functions:

```
def diffcheck(column):
    if column.values.sum() == 0:
        return True
    val0 = column.iat[0]
    check = val0 == column
    return check.values.sum() < len(check)
```

Function is applied for all rows, not only for first 5:

```
def q_v_plaus1(qs,vs):
    qs = qs.values
    vs= vs.values
    m1 = (qs== 0) & (vs > 0)
    m2 = (qs> 0) & (vs == 0)
    return ~(m1 | m2)
```

is rewritten to faster alternative:

```
def q_v_plaus1(qs,vs):
    qs = qs.values
    vs= vs.values
    m1 = (qs!= 0) | (vs <= 0)
    m2 = (qs<= 0) | (vs != 0)
    return m1 & m2
```

Comment: Added the functions, the third one is almost the same as the second one, just with a bit different logic.

Comment: @Morb - I am a bit confused, `q_v_plaus` is call only for first 5 rows? Not for all rows?

Comment: The DataFrame only has 5 rows. Before the qualitycheck function is called an original DataFrame is divided into those chunks of 5 rows (which is relevant for `diffcheck`)

Comment: @Morb - hmmm, is possible create chunk 1000 ?

Comment: The thing is every row is one minute of traffic data. And the `diffcheck` value needs to be calculated over a timeframe of 5 minutes.

Comment: So i just tried out your proposed changes. With the rewritten function I don't see any significant improvement. And when I use the way without `assign` the time for one call of `qualitycheck` increases to around 500ms.

Comment: @Morb - Problem is you call function for 5 rows, try change it to 1000 or more.

Comment: Mhm thank you. I changed it so that the whole dataframe is passed to the function. And now only `diffcheck` will be called for every 5 rows, but the rest of the assignments is done for all 500,000 rows at once. Works way faster that way.